# Where is the coding error for the unexpected '}' in this if / else choice of loops?

Tags: wp-query

an unexpected '}'  is reported for } else {

```php
<?php
function mg_get_selected_taxonomy_dropdown_term() {
  return isset( $_GET[ 'state' ] ) && $_GET[ 'state' ] ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'state' ] ) : '';
  }
      $selected_term = mg_get_selected_taxonomy_dropdown_term();
      $states = get_terms('state'); $i = 0;

      if ($selected_term != "ALL") {
        foreach ( $states as $state ) :

        $doctors = new WP_Query(array(
         'post_type'      => 'doctor',
         'orderby'        => 'name',
         'order'          => 'ASC',
         'post_status'    => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'tax_query'      => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'state',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $state->slug
          ),
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'state',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $selected_term,
          ),
        )
      )); 
      } else {
        foreach ( $states as $state ) :

        $doctors = new WP_Query(array(
         'post_type'      => 'doctor',
         'orderby'        => 'name',
         'order'          => 'ASC',
         'post_status'    => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'tax_query'      => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'state',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $state->slug
          ),
        )
      ));

      }
?>
```

Comment: Indent the code and it should be a lot easier to find the missing braces, any decent editor will auto=indent code for you so it's effortless

Comment: you are missing the `endforeach;` - once that is added, you need to close `}` the if/else and end the function `}`

Comment: Thanks Michael. I inherited the code from the prior developer and am adding select functionality to the code. It has the endforeach at the end of the template where $doctors is used in an if ($doctors->have_posts() ) loop. It must not be read with my code change for the $selected_term. I'll work on that and see if that fixes it.